# Split and create a new dataframes for each variable in a specific column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm not exactly sure how to make progress on this question. I'm using here this `mtcars` dataset:

```
structure(list(index = 1:32, car = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", 
"Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", "Valiant", 
"Duster 360", "Merc 240D", "Merc 230", "Merc 280", "Merc 280C", 
"Merc 450SE", "Merc 450SL", "Merc 450SLC", "Cadillac Fleetwood", 
"Lincoln Continental", "Chrysler Imperial", "Fiat 128", "Honda Civic", 
"Toyota Corolla", "Toyota Corona", "Dodge Challenger", "AMC Javelin", 
"Camaro Z28", "Pontiac Firebird", "Fiat X1-9", "Porsche 914-2", 
"Lotus Europa", "Ford Pantera L", "Ferrari Dino", "Maserati Bora", 
"Volvo 142E"), mpg = c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 
24.4, 22.8, 19.2, 17.8, 16.4, 17.3, 15.2, 10.4, 10.4, 14.7, 32.4, 
30.4, 33.9, 21.5, 15.5, 15.2, 13.3, 19.2, 27.3, 26, 30.4, 15.8, 
19.7, 15, 21.4), cyl = c(6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 8, 6, 8, 4), 
    disp = c(160, 160, 108, 258, 360, 225, 360, 146.7, 140.8, 
    167.6, 167.6, 275.8, 275.8, 275.8, 472, 460, 440, 78.7, 75.7, 
    71.1, 120.1, 318, 304, 350, 400, 79, 120.3, 95.1, 351, 145, 
    301, 121), hp = c(110, 110, 93, 110, 175, 105, 245, 62, 95, 
    123, 123, 180, 180, 180, 205, 215, 230, 66, 52, 65, 97, 150, 
    150, 245, 175, 66, 91, 113, 264, 175, 335, 109), drat = c(3.9, 
    3.9, 3.85, 3.08, 3.15, 2.76, 3.21, 3.69, 3.92, 3.92, 3.92, 
    3.07, 3.07, 3.07, 2.93, 3, 3.23, 4.08, 4.93, 4.22, 3.7, 2.76, 
    3.15, 3.73, 3.08, 4.08, 4.43, 3.77, 4.22, 3.62, 3.54, 4.11
    ), wt = c(2.62, 2.875, 2.32, 3.215, 3.44, 3.46, 3.57, 3.19, 
    3.15, 3.44, 3.44, 4.07, 3.73, 3.78, 5.25, 5.424, 5.345, 2.2, 
    1.615, 1.835, 2.465, 3.52, 3.435, 3.84, 3.845, 1.935, 2.14, 
    1.513, 3.17, 2.77, 3.57, 2.78), qsec = c(16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 
    19.44, 17.02, 20.22, 15.84, 20, 22.9, 18.3, 18.9, 17.4, 17.6, 
    18, 17.98, 17.82, 17.42, 19.47, 18.52, 19.9, 20.01, 16.87, 
    17.3, 15.41, 17.05, 18.9, 16.7, 16.9, 14.5, 15.5, 14.6, 18.6
    ), vs = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), am = c(1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), gear = c(4, 4, 4, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4), carb = c(4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 
    2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 
    2, 2, 4, 6, 8, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is the pseudo-code that I have written.

```
for (i in 1:length(car)) {
  mtcars %>%
  filter(car == car[i]) %>%
  mtcars_i <- mtcars
}
```

The idea here is that I would like create 32 different datasets with the name of each car in the label for this particular dataset.

```
mtcars_mazda_rx4
mtcars_hornet_sportabout
etc.
```

Here `mtcars_mazda_rx4` would be a dataframe with all the same variables but only one observation, where `car == "Mazda RX4"`, i.e. `mtcars[car == "Mazda RX4",]`

Is there a way to create a for loop that filters the dataframe by a specific variable, and then outputs a new dataframe with that variable name identified in the new df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `assign`

```
for (i in 1:length(car)) {
  tmp <- mtcars %>%
  filter(car == car[i])
  assign(paste0('mtcars_', car[i]), tmp)
}
```

Comment: @hachiko <- you may use `car  <- na.omit(car)` and then loop

Comment: I've discovered that I have the same error with each of my most recent posts - trying to take the code from the mtcars version to a larger dataframe -- I get an error message that says "object Plant.Name not found" (Plant.Name is my version of "car") I'm having trouble figuring out what that means - do you have any ideas?

Comment: na.omit is a good idea instead of %>% filter(!is.na(car) bc it looks a little faster

Comment: @hachiko But `na.omit` adds an attribute. although in this case, it is okay

Comment: @hachiko can you show values of `car`

Answer (score 2):

Just a different approach using `split`; I am using `dplyr` to make the solution more legible;

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
#  rownames_to_column("car") %>% ## run this line if you are using original mtcars
  split(., .$car) %>% 
  set_names(., nm = paste0("mtcars_", names(.))) %>% 
  list2env(., envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: hm I'm getting a weird error that says
Error: caused by error in 'repaired_names()': ! Names must be unique. x These names are duplicated: "Plant.Name" at locations 23 and 25

Comment: you forgot to share your error. by any chance it says column name should not be duplicated? Here, I am using the original `mtcars` dataset which has the car names in its rownames. For your dataset, you don't need the second line (`rowname_to_column`). Just remove that line.